# pyads : Failed to open port on AMS router

Tags: ads, twincat-ads

I am trying to connect a Windows PC to a Beckhoff PLC using pyads library. I installed Twincat ADS 3.1 on my Windows PC and created routes both on the PC and the PLC. When testing the connection with TcAdsTest (in the Twincat folder), everything works fine. But with my python script, I get an error message : **"Failed to open port on AMS router"**.

My python code is as follows :

```
import pyads

plc = pyads.Connection('5.134.132.47.1.1', 851, '10.10.13.200')
plc.open()
```

I also converted my python script into an executable file.
When I launch the .exe, the connection is successfull. It seems that only the .py leads to an error.

Is there some issue with my admin rights on the python script ? I tried running my .py with VSCode as Administrator but I still get the same error message.

Comment: hi, how do you know the connection is successful on the exe? Is that python code the exact code that was made into the exe, if so, this would not produce an error, only crash the exe? Can you please check your firewall settings (https://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1031/tc3_ads_intro/115824651.html&id=), does the route dialog show connected on the PC?

Comment: hi, connection is successfull on the exe because after `plc.open()`, I call `plc.is_open()` which returns True. The python script is exactly the same as the exe. Firewall is off both on PLC and PC. The route dialog shows connected.

Comment: is your plc program running? the port 851 is only opened if your plc project is running

Comment: yes, it is running, and I can successfully connect to port 851 with TcAdsTest using the same AMS NetId as in the script

Comment: the open() and is_open() only connect and tell you if you are connected to the TwinCat message router and not the PLC. Can you try reading a variable using the exe and see if this works. When do you get the AMS error, after the open() call?

Comment: I can read and write variables using the .exe. Only the .py does not work

Comment: this is curious, given the exe works, i am curious if this is related to how the library is installed / ran when running from vs code, are you using a venv?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by reinstalling python !
My python.exe was originally downloaded from the Microsoft Store. Its path was ~AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe.
I uninstalled it and downloaled Python3.11.7 from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). The new path is ~AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe

Everything seems to work now.

Comment: thanks for posting your resolution to this, not sure why the specific install of python should affect pyADS, but will look into it.