TwinCat python ads communication
I am not able able to establish any connection with Twincat beckoff plc using python, can anyone please help?
here is my code,
#running at sneha mam's laptop 
import pyads

# Define the AMS Net ID and the port for ADS communication
AMS_NET_ID = '192.168.1.6.1.1'  # Your PLC's AMS Net ID
ADS_PORT = 851  # Standard ADS port

# def check_connection():
    # Create a connection object
print("Creating connection object...")
plc = pyads.Connection(AMS_NET_ID, ADS_PORT)

try:
    # Open the connection
    print("Opening connection...")
    plc.open()

    print("Connection to PLC successful.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to connect to PLC: {e}")
finally:
        # Ensure the connection is closed if it was opened
    if plc.is_open:  # Access as a property, not a method
        plc.close()
        print("Connection closed.")
    else:
        print("Connection was not open.")

And, here is my output,
Creating connection object...
Opening connection...
Failed to connect to PLC: Failed to open port on AMS router.
Connection was not open.

Has a route been created to and from the PC running TwinCAT?

did you check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880074/pyads-failed-to-open-port-on-ams-router
